# CSS absolute position not being put in the correct location

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to produce mailing list labels from a database connected to a website (yes, I could grab the list in some text format and import to something like Word... but ultimately I'm not going to be preparing the mailing so I want as few steps as possible in the process!). I've managed to get it working except for one part: the labels are not positioned correctly vertically.

I've looked at a number of questions on SO over the last few hours but none of the questions (or solutions) quite match what I've got.

I've defined 3 different paragraph classes for the 3 labels across the page (there's wierd gaps in the labels we've got for printing), with dimensions based on the label positions and size. Each label is a single paragraph with one of the 3 classes, and banks of labels sit inside a div representing the pages (these take into account the top and bottom margins of the pages).

Horizontally, it's working fine; vertically is another matter. Firebug is showing the paragraphs overlapping. I'm stumped as to what's going on.

Here's the CSS:

```
body
{
    color: Black;
    background-color: White;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
p.print_label_left, p.print_label_right, p.print_label_middle
{
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 5.4cm;
    height: 1.43cm;
    max-height: 1.43cm;
    min-height: 1.43cm;
    margin-left: 0.5cm;
    margin-top: 1.48cm;
    margin-right: 0.5cm;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    padding: 0.5cm;
    top: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: solid 1px black;
}
p.print_label_left
{
    left: 0.65cm;
}
p.print_label_middle
{
    left: 7.3cm;
}
p.print_label_right
{
    left: 13.95cm;
}
div.print_page
{
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 21cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
    border: none;
}
```

And here's a representative HTML sample (I can't give the real stuff due to privacy):

```
<body>
<div class="print_page" style="top:-1.33333333333cm;">
<p class="print_label_left" style="top:0cm;">A<br />
B<br />
C<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_middle" style="top:0cm;">D<br />
E<br />
F<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_right" style="top:0cm;">G<br />
H<br />
I<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_left" style="top:2.43cm;">J<br />
K<br />
L<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_middle" style="top:2.43cm;">M<br />
N<br />
O<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_right" style="top:2.43cm;">P<br />
Q<br />
R<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

The header defines a doctype (xhtml transitional 1.0) and I've played around with the max-height and min-height and putting extra lines in each paragraph to try to force it to have sufficient content to fill out the text, but no such luck.

When I print out the list, the outlines indicate the boxes are spaced at 2cm intervals not the required 2.43cm. And I'm fresh out of ideas of things to search for!

If it helps, I'm using Firefox 36 on a Windows 7 x64 machine but the server I'm running this on is a typical LAMP setup.

Comment: Providing a codepen would make it easier for people to see the problem in question: http://codepen.io/

Comment: Also, cm is generally not advised for screen usage: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: @grill, this is intended for printing, not for screen (I assumed the mention of mailing list labels might've made that obvious without stating that explicitly...). Different browser/printer combos render px differently, but cm is consistent regardless. It's important because I'm not necessarily the one who's going to be printing these.

Comment: @grill, fwiw, here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bu93h6kg/. Not that it helps since the output display doesn't really show the problem... other than that the size of the first row of boxes is meant to be the same as the second, but it isn't because the second row is being positioned too high

Answer (score 0):

It's should work if i understand your question?

```css
body
{
    color: Black;
    background-color: White;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
p.print_label_left, p.print_label_right, p.print_label_middle
{
    background: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0.5px;
    top: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: solid 1px black;
}
p.print_label_left
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
p.print_label_middle
{
    margin-left: 150px;
}
p.print_label_right
{
    margin-left: 300px;
  
}
div.print_page
{
    background: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border: none;
    outline: solid 5px Red;
}
```

```html
<div class="print_page">
<p class="print_label_left">A<br />
B<br />
C<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_middle">D<br />
E<br />
F<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_right">G<br />
H<br />
I<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_left">J<br />
K<br />
L<br />
</p>
<p class="print_label_middle">M<br />
N<br />
O<br />
</p>
```

Comment: Appreciate the attempt, @Milad, but that's not it (that's very similar to what I had to begin with :-/ ). Each group of 3 paragraphs is meant to be aligned across the page, with the next row then in a line across underneath; this is why I had the position:absolute (ftr, I've also tried float:left with no success at all). It has to be in cm, since my experience with different browser/printer combos means the results don't print correctly in all cases when using px.